# Is there a generalization of directed graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology

I have been taking a course on graph theory recently and we are discussing generalizations of graphs, especially graphs as examples of simplicial complexes of 1- and 0-simplices. However, this generalization seems to only work with *undirected* graphs, possibly leaving *directed* graphs out of the picture. I am aware that, while considering hypergraphs as generalizations of graphs, then directed graphs can be seen as special instances of [directed hypergraphs](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2016.03.016), but is there something similar for when viewing graphs as instances of simplicial complexes?

Comment: Maybe this: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/directed+topological+space

Comment: That sounds very close, I will look into it at more depth later in day. Thank you, Qiaochu.

Comment: Simplicial sets are simplicial complexes where every simplex is oriented. I.e directed. You should look into it.